# htaccess with php template does not display images

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

I'm updating a website for someone from HTML to PHP.  I decided to use templates (top.php & bottom.php) for the top and bottom.  I got everything working fine but when the template loads anything from the top.php or bottom.php that is more than one directory deep it gets a 307 error.

```
[Root]
+ pages
  - index.php
  - admin_main.php
  - page1.php
+ layout
  - android.css
  - android-sprites.png
  - desktop.css
  - desktop-sprites.png
  - desktop-top.php
  - desktop-bottom.php
  - iphone.css
  - iphone-sprites.png
  - mobile-top.php
  - mobile-bottom.php
  - template.php          // Determines Mobile or Desktop
+ images
  + imgdir
    - dirimg.jpg
  - image1.jpg
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Redirects
# ==================================================

RewriteRule ^\.(jpg|png)$              - [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)/$              /pages/admin_$1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$                    /pages/$1.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^$                         /pages/index.php [NC,L]

# ==================================================

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

</IfModule>
```

images/image1.jpg show up fine, however images/imgdir/dirimg.jpg send a 307 error.  It appears to only happen in the bottom.php portion of the template.

The line reads:

```
<img src="/images/imgdir/dirimg.jpg" />
```

Also, any other recommendations are welcomed!

Comment: You tried putting the `RewriteCond`'s before your `RewriteRules` ?

Comment: Yes, It didn't help. :(

Comment: Does it say anything in your console or error logs?

Comment: No, it doesn't how any errors in the error.log and the access.log show all the other files being accessed, but just skips over that one.

Comment: Try the absolute path - i.e. `http://localhost/path/toimage/image.jpg`

Comment: shows up fine in browser if typed in url bar.  Tried absolute img src and still nothing.

Comment: Apparently it's an issue with Google Chrome.  Firefox works fine.  IE works fine with the exception of the layout being messed up as usual.